# Not able to add default connection in appsetting.json file. in .net6

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net-core, entity-framework-core, .net-6.0

when i'm try to add default connection in appsettings.json file. i'm getting zero suggestion after writing double quotes and moreover  also getting an error like "only one top level item is allowed in a json document"

```
"ConnectionStrings": {

"DefaultConnection":"Server:.;Database=Bulky; Trusted_Connection:True;" 

  }
```

Comment: Is the double : : a typo there?

Comment: I have mistakenly enter wrong here. still getting the same error "System.IO.InvalidDataException: 'Failed to load configuration from file 'G:\personal project\main\personal\appsettings.json'.' "

Comment: Is this the whole `appsettings.json`?

Comment: If that's the whole `appsettings.json` file, you're missing the top-level `{..}` braces: `{"ConnectionStrings:{"DefaultConnection":"..."}}`

Comment: What you posted isn't a valid JSON document, it's missing the top-level brackets. That's what the error complains about: `"only one top level item is allowed in a json document"`.

Comment: There's no "default" connection either - appsettings is just a JSON settings file and `DefaultConnection` is just a name. You could have used something more descriptive, eg `Reports` or `Sales`. When you use `Configuration.GetConnectionString("Reports")` .NET will check *all* config values loaded from files, env variables, the command line and any other source and read the contents of the `Reports` key in the `ConnectionStrings` section. If you have an env variable or CLI parameter with a matching name, they'll override `appsettings` simply because env variables are loaded after JSON files

Answer (score 1):

your appsettings.json file should be like this

```
{
 "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=xxx;Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=True;",
    "AnotherConnection": "Data Source=xxxx;Initial Catalog=xxx;Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=True;"
  },
 "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

notice that if you have several connections you need to separate them by " , "